# Android:exported needs to be specific for element

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-12, manifest-merging

Where should I add android:exported="true" ?

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.ballsort.m14gaming" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:exported="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:name="com.ballsort.m14gaming.UnityPlayerActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
      <meta-data android:name="android.notch_support" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="unity.build-id" android:value="a152d38f-fdbc-4597-8cb0-05e3b109fb15" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="0" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-enable" android:value="True" />
    <meta-data android:name="notch.config" android:value="portrait|landscape" />
  </application>
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vulkan" android:required="false" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

This is the error specified in Merged Manifest

Merging errors
Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specific for element <activity#com.unity.purchasing.googleplay.VRPurchaseActivity>.Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for 'android:exported' when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. Ball_Sort_Blue_-_Puzzle_Game main manifest (this file) line 26

Answer (score 0):

Many times it happens where libraries are not maintained with new api rules  or project is using it's old version so if you are able to upgrade your library then you can go with that way otherwise you can just register that activity in your manifest with `android:exported="true/false"` . In your case, copy activity registration stuff from merged manifest and add `android:exported` like this

```
<activity#com.unity.purchasing.googleplay.VRPurchaseActivity android:exported="true" />
```